# Convert an int list into an int number

Tags: python, algorithm, list, int, converters

Programming in Python, I would like to know how to convert:

```
lst = [1,2,3,4]
```

to:

```
lst = 1234
```

I need to make a int with the values of the list

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Why do you have a list of digits at all?

Comment: @user2357112 Why does it matter why he wants to do it or how he ended up with this list?

Comment: @SethMMorton: Because usually, when someone wants to do something weird, it's because they're using the wrong approach to do something else, and the best solution involves changing some other part of the code.

Comment: @user2357112 I'm not so sure this is something weird.  Besides, this is a Q&A site, and even if this question was for purely educational reasons it is a legit question with a straightforward answer.  It shouldn't matter why they want to know how to do it.

Comment: @SethMMorton: If we want to provide the best solution to the actual problem, it matters. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: @SethMMorton: We can, of course, answer the question they originally asked (unless it's meaningless or ridiculously hard, which isn't the case here) _as well as_ solving their real problem. But not _instead of_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious way to do it is to convert each number to a string, join the strings, then convert back to an integer:

```
>>> numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> digits = [str(number) for number in numbers]
>>> digits
['1', '2', '3', '4']
>>> numeral = ''.join(digits)
>>> numeral
'1234'
>>> number = int(numeral)
>>> number
1234
```

Of course you can merge this all into a single expression pretty easily:

```
>>> number = int(''.join(str(number) for number in numbers))
```

---

The other obvious way to do it is mathematically:

```
>>> number = 0
>>> for digit in numbers:
...     number = number * 10 + digit
>>> number
1234
```

This one is a bit tougher to put into a single expression, so I'll leave it as an exercise for the reader. (See [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) for the easiest way.)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure how you ended up in this predicament, but you can use `reduce` to keep shifting the digits by 10

```
a_list = [1,2,3,4]
reduce(lambda x,y: x*10+y, a_list)
```

Comment: Probably how `int(str)` is implemented internally.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: No. You might want to look at [the CPython code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Objects/longobject.c#l2008), but basically, it adds and carries from the right instead of multiplying and adding from the left (and adds a bunch of clever optimizations on top of that).

Answer (score 4):

Easiest way is to just make it a `str` then an `int`

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> int(''.join(map(str, lst)))
1234
```

If each element of the list is a single digit you can also do something like,

```
>>> def lst_to_int(l):
...     return sum(d*10**i for i, d in enumerate(reversed(l)))
... 
>>> lst_to_int(lst)
1234
```